# how can i print only my custom errror message without printing all the stack trace in testng through try catch block

Tags: java, testng

`@Test(dataProvider = "FileDataProvider2")
    public void testModifiedFiles(String excelData2, String csvData)throws Exception {
            try{
            List<List<String>> excelList2 = ReadFromFile.readexcelFile(excelData2);
            List<List<String>> csvList1 = ReadFromFile.readCSVFile(csvData);
            logger.info("Test by Missing some data");
            Assert.assertEquals(excelList2, csvList1);
            }
            catch(Throwable e){
                Assert.fail("Data Misseddddddddddd..............", e);
            }
    }`

> 2016-05-11 00:17:35 INFO  TestClassToCompare:72 - Test by Missing
>   some data [Utils] Attempting to create
>   D:\workspace\ReadExcelCSVFiles\test-output\Default suite\Default
>   test.html [Utils]   Directory
>   D:\workspace\ReadExcelCSVFiles\test-output\Default suite exists: true
>   [Utils] Attempting to create
>   D:\workspace\ReadExcelCSVFiles\test-output\Default suite\Default
>   test.xml [Utils]   Directory
>   D:\workspace\ReadExcelCSVFiles\test-output\Default suite exists: true
>   FAILED: testModifiedFiles("C:/Users/leela
>   krishna/Desktop/Xlsx/company_modified.xlsx", "C:/Users/leela
>   krishna/Desktop/CSV/companies.csv") java.lang.AssertionError: Data
>   Misseddddddddddd..............    at
>   org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:83)    at
>   com.qpair.readfile.ReadExcelCSVFiles.TestClassToCompare.testModifiedFiles(TestClassToCompare.java:76)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:646)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:823)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1131)  at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:778)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1225)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1150)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1075)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1047)   at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:137)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:58) Caused
>   by: java.lang.AssertionError: lists don't have the same size expected
>   [67] but found [66]   at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:94)   at
>   org.testng.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:513)  at
>   org.testng.Assert.assertEqualsImpl(Assert.java:135)   at
>   org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:116)   at
>   org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:389)   at
>   org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:556)   at
>   org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:533)   at
>   com.qpair.readfile.ReadExcelCSVFiles.TestClassToCompare.testModifiedFiles(TestClassToCompare.java:73)
>     ... 25 more
>
> ===============================================
>       Default test
>
> ## Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
>
> =============================================== Default suite Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
>   ===============================================`

Answer (score 0):

In Java, Instead of printing total exception 'e' just try once with printing only cause of exception.

```
    System.out.println(e.getCause());
```

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: I tried it. it did not printed any stack trace but for a failure test case it says  the test is passed, which is not correct.

Comment: i mean to say use e.getCause() in ur assertion like this Assert.fail("Data Misseddddddddddd..............", e.getCause());

Comment: still getting all the stack trace printed.

Comment: `catch(AssertionError e){
    Assert.fail("Data Misseddddddddddd..............", e.getCause());`


used like this

Comment: Actually in java prospective e.getCause prints only cause like no such element exception etc..  but in Assertions it looks like they are printing total message. So may need to override it to print cause and try..means create some custom class in testng see here https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/asserts/LoggingAssert.java

Answer (score 0):

If you want a pop-up then you can use

```
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
```

OR

```
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + "My Custom error");
```

Demo as below :-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot move file");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + "My Custom error");
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: I used the same in my code in catch block. but no use it still printing all the stack trace when assertion fails.

Comment: in that case simple use :-  System.out.println("My Custom error");

Comment: You can also add any logger if you want to log-it for future reference